# MAX from Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

How do I find the maximum value of a particular column from the result of a SubQuery?

For example, if the result of the subquery is:

```
10
20
30
```

How do I get maximum from this, in this case 30?

Comment: What did you try *yourself*?

Comment: What was the subquery ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example :

If query `SELECT id FROM test_table;` returns output like

```
10
20
30
```

Now use sub query to find Maximum do like

```
SELECT MAX(a.id) FROM (SELECT id FROM test_table) a;
```

Comment: If Strict Mode is On in MySQL, it does not work

Comment: This should work in all modes. What error do you get?

Comment: @ypercube "Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause"

Comment: Then you are using a different query, not this one.

Comment: set session sql_mode= 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
select max(id) from (SELECT 0 as id
    UNION SELECT 1
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5
) as id;

This query returns "5"

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table where aa >= all (SELECT aa FROM test_table);
```

Comment: Any explanation for the down votes? This code does work afterall.

Comment: @Paul I wonder, too. It won't work if there is a `NULL` in the subquery results but the downvotes might be because there was no explanation.

Comment: This is actually even better than the `MAX` solution, for example when there is an index on the queried column in a very basic subselect. In this case the optimizer practically removes all additional computation with this query (at least in decent versions of MySQL), but iterates the rows twice in the other solution. Maybe add an explanation to your answer and an example, with the output of `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: @GhostGambler It really depends on what the actual subquery is and on the DBMS. We don't really know anything about those factors, there is no mention of MySQL in the question.

Comment: @ypercube There is one in the comments to the other answer.

Comment: I didn't vote, but this query will return multiple rows if the highest value in the table has duplicates.

Comment: First answers from new users go to a review queue automatically, with limited context. I suspect the down-voters regarded the answer as a low-quality single line of code answer, which is generally discouraged. I'm just guessing though. It is quite a poor question after all.

Comment: first of all, I've tested this query on oracle -> when there wasn't tag 'mysql'. Secondly, usage of ">= all" could be in some cases more efficient than max function. Today I was able to see this again replacing the function max with ">= all" while searching a relatively large amount of data